# EF Best practices - Shadow Properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I generally create a domain model and use data annotations/explicit foreign key relationships in that domain model to define how the database is created.  To me, this makes certain rules (like max length or required) clear and in one place.

I was going through a code review and one part of the feedback was to not do either of those things.  They recommended I do everything in the configuration for each model using Fluent API/shadow properties instead so that all database generation code is in one place and that the model stays clean and only concerns itself with the domain alone.

As an example, I updated my code to something similar to this:

```
public class Blog
  {   
    private HashSet<Comment> comments;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Comment> Comments => comments;    
    public string Title {get; private set;}
    public string Content {get; private set;}
    public Core.Constants.Blog.Categories Category {get; private set;}

    public Blog(string title, string content, Core.Constants.Blog.Categories category)
    {
      Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
      comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
      Title = title;
      Content = content;
      Category = category;
    }
  }

public class Comment{
    private string Id {get; private set;}
    public string Identifier { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }    
    
    public Comment(string identifier, string description)
    {
      Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
      Identifier = identifier;
      Description = description;
    }
}
```

and added fluent configuration code with:

```
internal class BlogConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Domain.Blog>
  {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Domain.Blog> builder)
    {
      builder.ToTable("Blog");

      builder.HasKey("Id").HasName("PK_Blog");

      builder.Property(res => res.Title)
            .IsRequired();

      builder.Property(res => res.Content)
            .IsRequired();
      
      builder.Metadata
          .FindNavigation(nameof(Domain.Blog.Comments))          
          .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
          
      builder.Property(blog => blog.Category)
             .HasConversion(value =>
                                  value.ToString(),
                                  convertedValue => Enum.Parse<Core.Constants.Blog.Categories>(convertedValue));

    }
  }
  
   internal class CommentConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Domain.Comment>
  {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Domain.Comment> builder) {
      builder.ToTable("Comment");

      builder.HasKey("Id").HasName("PK_Comment");

      builder.Property(asset => asset.Identifier)
            .HasMaxLength(25) 
            .IsRequired();

      builder.Property(asset => asset.Description)
           .HasMaxLength(250);

      builder.HasIndex(asset => asset.Identifier).IsUnique();
    }
  }
```

My questions are:

1. In my actual project, I need a navigation property filled from "Comment" back to "Blog".  Is it bad to add an explicitly navigation property on Comment that points back to Blog that is ignored in the fluent configuration?
2. Is using Data Annotations on the domain model really that bad of a practice?

Comment: Why would you "ignore a navigation property in the fluent configuration"?

Comment: Sorry, it was a poorly worded question.  Using, Fluent API in the example above (without the navigation back to Blog), the foreign key is created via Fluent API.  The feedback I received was summarized to say, the domain model is configured to reflect reality where comments are only accessed via the blog.  So my question is, is it against best practices to have the nav property from Comment back to Blog or should I be enforcing the access pattern of accessing comments via the Blog.  Are there issues with the domain reflecting whats possible via the db vs what is supposed to happen in reality?

Comment: If you don't want to promote querying Comments directly, then sure you can omit the Comment->Blog navigation property and omit the DbSet<Comment> property on your DbContext.  But it's just a design decision, not a best practice.